# How to show Windows Phone application to client before publish in store

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

I have developed Windows Phone Silverlight application (support 8.0 and 8.1) for my client request. The client is goint to publish the application in WP app store, but first he must check on his phone if everything is OK with the application.
The application was developed with Visual Studio 2013, I've got developer account and own phone assigned to this account on which I have tested the application.

The question is, how can my client install the application on his own phone skipping windows app store? I have sent him builded *.xap file but he had a some problems with installation (Cannot install company application)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can submit your app to Windows Phone Store BETA. Your app will by certified quickly, and your client will be able to download it just like any other app from Store. The difference is that it will be visible and possible only for him.

Log in to you **DevCenter** account, click **Submit App**. Then, in **App info** section expand **More options** and select **Beta**. Then you can provide your client's mail.

[image: screenshot]

I'm not sure, but I think that the name of the app should not be the same as the final version. So you can name it "My App Beta" to avoid future name conflict with the final version.

One more thing. When your app pass certification process, you have to send the link to the app to your client, because he won't get any notification.

Comment: Man it would be sweet if you could beta a specific version.